# Multiplying Out Inner Products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, inner-products

If I have a product of the form $(x-s)^tA(x-s)$ where $x$ and $s$ are vectors and $A$ is a matrix, how would I go about multiplying this out?  Further, how would I go about taking its derivative?

Comment: You have a matrix times a matrix times a matrix. Do you know matrix multiplication?

Comment: You also need to be specific about what derivative you are taking respect to.

Comment: Apologizes for the delay, I did mean the derivative, or gradient I suppose, with respect to x or s, if we define the above to be some function f(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiplying it out, you can use the fact that inner products are positive definite symmetric bilinear forms (the 'bilinear' bit being the key one here), and revert to inner product notation, using the definition that $\langle x,y\rangle =x^TAy$:

$\langle x-s,x-s\rangle  = \langle x,x-s\rangle -\langle s,x-s\rangle  = \langle x,x\rangle  - \langle x,s\rangle  - \langle s,x\rangle  - \langle s,s\rangle $

And then use the fact that it's symmetric:

$=\langle x,x\rangle -2\langle x,s\rangle -\langle s,s\rangle $

and finally use the definition $\langle x,y\rangle =x^T Ay$ again:

$=x^TAx - 2(x^TAs) - s^TAs$

Regarding taking the derivative, note that $\frac{d}{dt}\langle x,y\rangle =\langle x',y\rangle +\langle x,y'\rangle $ (where the dash represents the derivative with respect to the single variable), and again use the symmetry of an inner product, and take it from there...

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very helpful!  Why though is the bilinear form equivalent to the inner product notation?  Is it not $x^ty$ = <x,y>?

Comment: You said that your $x^tAy$ was a product, so I assumed from that that you meant inner product. An inner product is simply a specific type of bilinear form. $x^Ty$ is definitely one inner product that exists, but there are many, and there is a lot to do with choice of basis, as any inner product can be made to look like the standard dot product ($x^Ty$) by choosing the right basis.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a vector $x \in k^n$ as an $n \times 1$ matrix, you need to use various algebraic properties in the ring of matrices (distributivity, associativity, etc.) and the fact that
$$
(x - s)^\top = x^\top - s^\top.
$$